# Can't access EC2 instance through public IP

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, dns

I am using `free tier` version of `Ubuntu` on `EC2`. My `Security group` looks like this:

[image]

After installing the apache server on `instance`. I can access it through `public IP address` and `public DNS`. But the `SSH` is only accessible   through `public DNS`. Why so? I am getting `Operation timed out` while running `sudo ssh -i developer.pem ubuntu@52.31.45.00`

Comment: There is no reason why it should work via DNS and not via IP - whenever this has happened to me in the past it's because of a typo :) - can you ping the DNS and confirm definitively it returns the same IP as the IP you are trying to ssh to?

Comment: I agree with @ChrisSimon. Can you post the output with `-v` option?

Comment: why are you using sudo for SSH? try with our the sudo and see if it works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

52.31.45.00 is unlikely to be a valid address

"0" addresses are allowed but apparently don't work with some equipment

See this answer on serverfault https://serverfault.com/questions/10985/is-x-y-z-0-a-valid-ip-address

So, to get access to your server by ip, use the correct ip number, not the one shown in your question

Comment: I haven't posted the real ip address due to security reasons. but still I am getting the same response

Comment: like the other commenters have said you need to give us the output of a ``ssh -v`` and I would add ``dig`` and ``dig -x`` to that